# Nested Navigators in React Navigation v6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

I'm struggling with some issues regarding the usage of React Navigation v6 with nested navigators.

Basically, I have a Drawer Navigator, which in one of the screens, contains a Bottom Tab Navigator, that in some screens contains some Stack Navigators. The hierarchy is something like this:

- Root Navigator (Stack Navigator)

  - Drawer Navigator (Navigator)

    - Customer (Bottom Tab Navigator)

      - Home (Screen)
      - Products (Stack Navigator)

        - All Products (Screen)
        - Categories (Screen)
      - Favorites (Screen)
      - Checkout (Stack Navigator)

        - Shopping Cart (Screen)
        - Checkout (Screen)
    - Settings (Screen)

My problem is, for example, on both of the stack navigators, I need to hide the bottom tabs and change the header (I use a custom bottom tabs menu and a custom header).

I coulnd't find a proper way of doing so, and when I try to filter by the active route, I don't really get the current screen that is focused, and always end up with the route name that is on top of everything else, in this case, the Drawer Navigator.

I'm stuck with this for a few days now.